Variance of a simple game
There are two boxes which are either filled or empty.  To start with, a uniformly random number from $\{0, 1, 2\}$ is chosen and that number of boxes are filled, uniformly at random. So there is a $\frac13$ probability that no boxes are filled, a $\frac13$ probability that both boxes are filled, a $\frac16$ probability that only box $A$ is filled and a $\frac16$ probability that only box $B$ is filled.
You don't see which boxes have been filled.  You can either open box $A$ or both boxes. It costs you $1$ to open box $A$ and $2$ to open boxes $A$ and $B$ together. There is no option to only open box $B$.  You are trying to show that both boxes have been filled.  You can give up on the pair of boxes at any time and ask for a new pair of boxes which will be filled anew to according the same (but independent) random process. You don't get any money back though.
You have two strategies. One is to open box $A$ first with cost 1. If it is filled you can then open boxes $A$ and $B$ with an additional cost of $2$. If box $B$ is not filled this has cost you $3$ so far and you have to try again.  The other strategy is to open both boxes $A$ and $B$ each time. This costs you $2$ for each pair of boxes until you succeed.
It turns out that either strategy costs $6$ on average.   For the strategy where you always open both boxes the variance is also $3^2(1-\dfrac{1}{3}) = 6$ .
What is the variance for the strategy where you first open the first box and only open the second if the first is filled?

The variance seems to be approximately $15$ from simulations, if that helps at all

@AP That is interesting. Is it very close to 15 in your simulation?

Running it five times has given $14.96874$, $14.97857$, $15.17439$, $14.96228$ and $15.21023$ as the estimated variances. Each simulation had about $30,000$ games.

Let $N$ denote the random number of trials, $C$ denote the total cost, and $C_i$ denote the cost of the $i^{\text{th}}$ trial. Using law of total variance, we know
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(C) = \mathbb{E}[\text{Var}(C|N)] + \text{Var}(\mathbb{E}[C|N]).
\end{align*}
Let us first compute the second term. Since there were $N$ trials, it implies that $N-1$ resulted in a failure (i.e., at least one box was empty) and the last one was successful. So let us first see the expected cost given that trial is a failure. Conditioned on trial being a failure, probability that box $A$ is empty is $3/4$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[C_i|F_i] = 1 \cdot \frac{3}{4} + 3 \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{2},
\end{align*}
where $F_i$ denotes that $i^{\text{th}}$ trial was a failure. Similarly,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[C_i^2|F_i] = 1 \cdot \frac{3}{4} + 9 \cdot \frac{1}{4} = 3.
\end{align*}
To compute $\mathbb{E}[C|N]$, note that the expected cost is $(N-1)$ times the expected cost under the event that a trial is a failure plus $3$, which corresponds to the cost of successful trial. Thus,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[C|N] = (N-1)\mathbb{E}[C_i|F_i] + 3 = \frac{3}{2} \cdot (N-1) + 3.
\end{align*}
Consequently,
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(\mathbb{E}[C|N]) = \text{Var}\left( \frac{3}{2} \cdot (N-1) + 3\right) = \frac{9}{4} \cdot \text{Var}(N) = \frac{9}{4} \cdot 6 = \frac{27}{2}.
\end{align*}
We used the fact that $N$ is a geometric random variable with parameter $1/3$. As a side note, we also have that $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[C|N]] = 6$, as mentioned in the post.
We now consider to the first term in the expression of $\text{Var}(C)$. Using a similar argument as before, note that the variance of $C$ is $(N-1)$ times the variance of a single trial conditioned on the fact that the trial is a failure, i.e., $(N-1) \text{Var}(C_i|F_i)$. We implicitly used the fact that the trials are independent and the cost of successful trial is fixed and hence has no variance. We have,
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(C_i|F_i) = \mathbb{E}[C_i^2|F_i] - (\mathbb{E}[C_i|F_i])^2 = 3 - \frac{9}{4} = \frac{3}{4}.
\end{align*}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\text{Var}(C|N)] = \mathbb{E}\left[(N-1) \cdot \frac{3}{4}\right] = \frac{3}{4} \cdot \mathbb{E}[N-1] = \frac{3}{4} \cdot 2 = \frac{3}{2}.
\end{align*}
On combining the relations, we obtain,
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(C) = \frac{3}{2} + \frac{27}{2} = 15.
\end{align*}
This matches the simulated result mentioned in the comments.

Is a trial opening either one of the two boxes ? Also, what is $A$?

By $A$ I meant box $A$. I have edited it for clarity. A trial is a single realization of the boxes $A$ and $B$. If $A$ is empty, it opens just one box and incurs a cost of $1$ and if $A$ is full, it opens two boxes and incurs a cost of $3$.
